# Grabbing parts of a regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am not sure how I can extract the variables or groups I created in my regular expression. Specifically `datetime` and `IP`. I have read other postings and the documentation but I am getting a bit confused. I was wondering if someone could generate an example for me to follow. What I would like to do is to be able to extract `datetime` and `IP` for later use. Perhaps stored in a variable to be called on later

sample log:

`log = 'Oct  7 13:24:36 192.168.10.2 2013: 10:07-13:24:35 httpproxy[15359]: id="0001"`

```
httpproxy515139 = re.compile(r'(?P<datetime>\w\w\w\s+\d+\s+\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)\s+(?P<IP>d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).*')
```

Comment: Your regex does not capture your sample log.

Comment: You're missing a backslash for the first `\d` in your IP named capture. See [link](http://regex101.com/r/qE3hF7).

Comment: @Jerry slight typo on my part. I like the website you sent me! +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sample should help you:

```
>>> import re
>>> sample = 'this is a sample text'
>>> third_word = re.compile(r'\S+ \S+ (?P<word>\S+) .*')
>>> ms = third_word.match(sample)
>>> ms.groupdict()
{'word': 'a'}
```

You need to access the `groupdict()` method of the returned match object.

Comment: I am going ot try this out! thanks for the help!